# Drag & drop and cut & paste not working

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone explain this clipboard behaviour?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31866/can-anyone-explain-this-clipboard-behaviour)

This is weird. I'm on OSX Lion, and sometimes both drag & drop and cut & paste stop working, at the same time. They stop working in any program, not just the Finder. And it's not just the shortcut: if I try to right click and select "Copy" it doesn't work either.

This has happened three times so far. A reboot fixes it, but it's annoying at best. Anyone with the same problem? Any solution?

Comment: This is a duplicate because you both have the same "cut & paste" stop working. Your question does also mention the drag & drop problem, but the overall question is the same: "Why is cut and paste not working?" I've also edited the other question to address the drag and drop issue. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the question is “Anyone with the same problem”: yes, it seems at least another StackExchange user has the same problem in “[Can anyone explain this clipboard behaviour?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31866)”.