# CoreDragCreate error - drag&drop and copy-paste stop working

Tags: macos, copy-paste, ui

From time to time drag&drop and copy-paste stop working. Somehow the clipboard machinery gets messed up (I suspect Microsoft Remote Desktop is causing it). In the console I see the following sequence when I try to drag something:

```
09-06-16 10:13:54,991 Finder[59451]: CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : Lock timeout
09-06-16 10:13:54,991 Finder[59451]: CoreDragCreate error: -4960
09-06-16 10:13:54,991 Finder[59451]: error in CoreDragDispose: -1850
```

The console displays similar lines for every application that I try to drag in.

What is causing this issue and how can it be fixed?

Comment: When this happens, does a reboot fix it? Your log file references Finder, is it only Finder where copy-paste stops working? or does it stop working in all programs? Is it copy-paste of files specifically that breaks, or is it all kinds of (textual) copy-pastes?

Comment: Both a reboot and a logout fixes things. Copy-paste (textual - have not tried files) and drag&drop stop working across all programs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is causing the issue, but the `pboard` process is responsible for copy and paste.  Restarting it might provide a fix (temporarily), and can be less disruptive than logging out.  From [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111076/22953):

> Check if the pboard daemon is running:
>
> `launchctl list | grep com.apple.pboard`
>
> If the pboard daemon is running, then stop and start it. If it's not running, start it:
>
> `launchctl stop com.apple.pboard`
>
> `launchctl start com.apple.pboard`
>
> Then, you may need to restart the application(s) where cut-and-paste is not working.

Comment: Sounds promising! I will verify this if the problem pops up again.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like I still need to restart each and every application I want to copy into.