# Paste clipboard not working

Tags: macos, copy-paste

Copy-paste stops working on my mac very soon after rebooting. It seems that  "paste" gets disabled. The suggestions proposed in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31866) (including launchctl start/stop suggestion) does not solve my problem. I am running macOS Sierra version 10.12.1. All the updates are installed. Any suggestions?

Comment: There wasn't an accepted solution in the question you linked (and all of them have votes) so which solution are you referring to that didn't work?  Please update your question with that info.

Comment: Are you sure it is not just the paste that stops working? The reason being, it is set up now to only keep pasted items to the clipboard for 2 mins now via Universal Clipboard. Some more info would be helpful such as, does this happen all the time etc..

Comment: When I reboot, it works for some time and then stops working. I do not what triggers it to stop working. It happens all the time once it stops working. I am not using universal clipboard (I am not copying across devices) and I am trying to paste immediately after copy.